# NullPointerException on SetAdapter With My FriendsArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, facebook-graph-api, android-arrayadapter

The exception is occurring on the line "rowTxt.setText" and I can't, for the life of me, figure out why.

Here's my code

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View rowView = convertView;

    if(rowView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(mResourceId, null);
    }

    Friend friend = mFriendsList.get(position);
    TextView rowTxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowtext);
    Log.i("name", friend.getmName());
    rowTxt.setText(friend.getmName());

    return rowView;
}
```

Logcat output:

> 04-24 04:07:14.093: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(553): Shutting down VM
>   04-24 04:07:14.093: WARN/dalvikvm(553): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at com.friendsapp.FriendsArrayAdapter.getView(FriendsArrayAdapter.java:46)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   04-24 04:07:14.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   04-24 04:07:14.182: WARN/ActivityManager(65):   Force finishing activity com.friendsapp/.FriendsActivity
>   04-24 04:07:14.973: WARN/ActivityManager(65): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44e9c3c8 com.friendsapp/.FriendsActivity}
>   04-24 04:07:17.822: DEBUG/dalvikvm(553): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5842 objects / 457336 bytes in 113ms
>   04-24 04:07:18.732: INFO/Process(553): Sending signal. PID: 553 SIG: 9
>   04-24 04:07:18.772: INFO/WindowManager(65): WIN DEATH: Window{4503df58 AtchDlg:com.friendsapp/com.friendsapp.FriendsActivity paused=false}
>   04-24 04:07:18.772: INFO/ActivityManager(65): Process com.friendsapp (pid 553) has died.
>   04-24 04:07:18.782: INFO/WindowManager(65): WIN DEATH: Window{44f78f88 com.friendsapp/com.friendsapp.FriendsActivity paused=false}
>   04-24 04:07:26.814: WARN/ActivityManager(65): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44e9c3c8 com.friendsapp/.FriendsActivity}
>   04-24 04:12:07.102: DEBUG/SntpClient(65): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

EDIT: I figured out the issue with the help of corlettk. In short, I was assigning my listadapter like so:

```
FriendsArrayAdapter fAdapter = new FriendsArrayAdapter(FriendsActivity.this, android.R.simple_list_item_1, mFriendsList);
```

I did this because initially I had a generic listadapter that did not accommodate my Friend object; never thought to change it.

So when setAdapter went into my FriendsArrayAdapter it searched the id of simple_list_item_1 for R.id.rowtext, which it did't find. The fix was to change the above call to

```
FriendsArrayAdapter fAdapter = new FriendsArrayAdapter(FriendsActivity.this, R.layout.row_layout, mFriendsList);
```

(row_layout is the name of my XML file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fly,

What's the output of that  `Log.i("name", friend.getmName());` statement? If *friend* is NOT null, then I'd guess that *rowTxt* is. Debug print it to find out...

Further I'd guesse that you've got yourself a dodgy view-ID; or maybe that view just hasn't been added to a collection. Are you missing some initialisation code earlier on?

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: Keith,

Thanks for the response. The i-log prints correctly with the friend's name. I may be missing initialization code somewhere. R.id.rowtext is a textview I created within an xml file called rowlayout.xml within res/layout. I did not make any effort to add rowlayout.xml to any collection; is this necessary? Thanks

Comment: I just did a Log.i("name", R.id.rowtext) and the id is coming back as 2131099650 in logcat. Doesn't look like that's the issue

Comment: Yeah but IS 2131099650 a valid view-id? I reiterate my initial point: Check that 'rowTxt' (not just the id) is not null; and if it is then check that the ID is valid (I can't tell from here) and that the-required-view does in-fact exist in the 'rowView'. And you really SHOULD be using your IDE's debugger for all this, in preference to debug-prints. All modern IDE's can debug a remote server. Look it up in your IDE's help, or google it.

Comment: Ah yes, rowTxt is null. Sorry I've immigrated from the world of lightweight linux IDE's like Geany and my standard debug is a putchar(). Given this new information, I'm gonna mess around with it again and I'll come back here with the result. thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out ;-)